# Extract the nodal admittance matrix of a given circuit in LTspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, nodal-analysis, admittance

I am wondering if there is a way to extract the Nodal admittance matrix of a very complicated circuit using LTspice. Like draw the circuit or automatically generate a netlist (in the case of a very complicated circuit -using python for instance-) and then ask LTspice to compute the Nodal admittance matrix. After all it is what is does to solve the circuit, right?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the circuit linear?  SPICE parses a conductance matrix and uses Gaussian elimination to solve for node voltages and branch currents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *After it is what is does to solve the circuit, right?*

That is incorrect.

No simulator that I'm aware of solves circuit model problems by understanding anything about admittance matrices (or  S parameters etc. for example). Simulators use entirely different algorithms altogether.

> I am wondering if there is a way to extract the Nodal admittance
> matrix of a very complicated circuit using LTspice.

No, that isn't likely to be possible. Of course, you can take the AC analysis results and fit them to a formula involving s and that might be of some use (trial and error needed). Then you are a little closer to finding the matrices.

Here's a [Q and A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91416/how-do-circuit-simulators-actually-work) that might help you understand how simulators work. Simple extract: -

> **The general equations produced are nonlinear differential algebraic
> equations which are solved using implicit integration methods,
> Newton's method and sparse matrix techniques.**

Comment: Understood, thank you!