# How do electronic design tools work

Tags: spice, multisim, tools, eda

I'm looking for some insight into how something like multisim actually works. If I understand correctly it has spice under the hood but how does it actually analyze the circuits?

Is there some numerical method it's using or is it performing nodal/mesh analysis on the circuit at run time?

Any info would be great at this point, I just need somewhere to start looking for how it actually works under the hood.

Comment: lots of matrix calculations

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 i figured that might the answer.

Comment: SPICE simulators are almost all based off of [Modified Nodal Analysis](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/mna/MNA2.html)

Comment: @helloworld922, to the point that if it isn't based on MNA, I wouldn't call it SPICE.

Comment: @The Photon - SPICE didn't use MNA but plain NA. MNA was introduced with SPICE2. But I agree nevertheless :-)

Comment: There's no upside though of using mesh vs nodal analysis, it seems to me the algebra still has to take place regardless of if it's mesh or nodal. Any input on that?

Comment: Yes, the number of variables and equations is going to be the same either way. But setting up the equations is really easy for node, requires some graph theory for mesh.

Comment: [related](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19198/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to understand this, I highly recommend a book by Dr. Farid Najm, called "Circuit Simulation".  If you follow the exercises in the book you can code a working simulator by the time you get to the end of the book, and you'll have a great working knowledge of how to read in a netlist, set up the MNA matrix and solve it, while dealing with issues like convergence problems and initial conditions.  I was able to code a working SPICE-like simulator from scratch in a couple of weeks of spare time, with reasonably good circuit models just by following the exercises in the book.

[Circuit Simulation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470538716)

Answer (score 0):

I think most books you'll find on SPICE are barely more than sales collateral for some particular program.

This is what normally happens as things mature. At first, you get wonderful, thorough-going teaching material that carefully walks you through things because the audience is new and the author know that there is a need to pick people up by their bootstraps. So you want to look for EARLY material, if possible. In this perspective, I'd recommend that you keep an eye out for Larry Nagel's Ph.D. thesis, UC Berkeley, circa 1975. I'm pretty sure you can find a copy if you go there and look in Evens Hall. But just write Berkeley about getting a copy, if you can't find one any other way. It includes an overview of the theory so that you get a feel for how the program approaches its work.

Personally, I also found that the 2nd edition of Semiconductor Device Modeling with SPICE, by Paolo Antognetti and Giuseppe Massobrio, to be fantastic, as well.

Others have already told you about the use of matrices. The way I approach nodal analysis actually came from my reading of the above materials, plus a few others, on how Spice works inside. I find it very easy to apply and use -- and frankly, better than any textbook I've read about mesh, nodal, etc.

Complex models are linearized, of course. And you need to be comfortable with the derivative not only as a first year course but as an operator function, I think.

The complexity comes in all the corner cases that make life difficult. Plus users who create impossible circuits, etc. But the above two sources I mentioned should give you all the right broad strokes to feel pretty comfortable.